# Monitoring PostgreSQL backup

Tags: postgresql, backup, monitoring

I am new to PostgreSQL and have questions regarding the backup procedure.

How do I check whether a PostgreSQL database was backed up successfully? 
And how do I monitor the backup?

I have tried the following command to backup the database, but there's no output:

```
pg_dump [connection-option...] [option...] [dbname]
```

Comment: What you show is not a runnable command.  It is the synopsis from the man page.  Please show the command you run.

Answer (score 1):

The test is to restore the backup somewhere else.

Monitoring can be done via the return code of `pg_dump`: if that isn't 0, something went wrong.